# How to create an object and then alter it

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, functions, scripting, ddl

I'm using sql server 2012:

I would like to script out creation of an object(if it doesn't exist first), and then alter it.

I'm trying to avoid the usual drop/create as it would impact stats.  It also has to do with how we're scripting out changes to the DB.

What I have:

```
Go
If object_id(N'My_Function', N'FN') IS NULL 
Begin
Create Function My_Function
(
    @SomeParameter int
)
Returns int
As
Begin
    -- Intentionally empty
End

 End

Go
-- A header/comments
Alter Function My_Function
(
@SomeParameter int
)
Returns int
As
Begin
Declare @returnValue int
    -- A bunch of sql code
Return @returnValue
End
Go
```

The problem I'm having is "Create" must be first in the script(or first after a "GO"), but I can't put a "GO" inside an "If" conditional.  Is there a way to conditionally create something if it doesn't exist, and then alter it later?

Comment: IN choose script options   you can make "Include if NOT EXISTS"   to False

Comment: Several tools will do it for you. I would just buy a tool and save precious time.

Comment: @AAron, I was using a scalar function as an example.  This script(template) would apply to other objects as well.

Comment: I kind of agree with @AlexKuznetsov. If you are going to write scripts to cover a variety of objects, and you are going to be doing this a lot, and you are not doing this solely for educational purposes, I would go spend a few hundred bucks on a tool that will do this with a few clicks, and will have already worked out many bugs you haven't even created yet. This is so prevalent I've blogged about it: http://madelinebertrand.com/2012/04/20/re-blog-the-cost-of-reinventing-the-wheel/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't put `CREATE FUNCTION` inside `IF` logic since it needs to be in its own batch.

I would do it this way. If the function doesn't exist yet, create an empty stub. Now you can always safely issue an alter.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.function_name') IS NULL
BEGIN
  DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'CREATE FUNCTION dbo.function_name()
    RETURNS INT 
    AS
    BEGIN
      RETURN (1);
    END';

  EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END

ALTER FUNCTION dbo.function_name
(
  ... more complex logic here ...
```

Unfortunately I know of no easy way to get SSMS to script it out this way for you, and even doing that through SMO or other methods is going to be a pain IMHO. Simply because the function has to be of the same type (IF, TVF, MSTVF), so your simple stub can't always be the same.

Wouldn't it be great [if SQL Server supported `CREATE OR REPLACE`](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/127219/create-or-replace)?

Comment: That looks like it will work.  Thanks for the help, and yea, SQL Server really should have Create or Replace functionality.